# How do I clear the row source of a combobox but leave the value selected

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I am relatively new to VBA and am learning on the fly. I am adapting code from another project to fit my needs and am having an issue.

I have a userform that has a combox box that is populated by an advanced filter. I need to use this filter in the next row of data so I am trying to clear the rowsource of the combobox but leave the selected value.

Everything in the ASales1_Change code works as expected. I get a list for that combobox and the second combobox like I want. But I need to clear out the row source from ASales2 in order to add information to the second row

Here is the code I have for the boxes in the first row of the sales order frame of the user form.

```
Private Sub ASales1_Change()

On Error Resume Next
Sheets("Products").Range("L4").Value = ASales1.Value

'run advanced filter to change productlist named range
Adv

'clear values for product and quantity
For X = 2 To 3
Me.Controls("ASales" & X).Value = ""
Next

'set productlist as rowsource for second control
Me.ASales2.RowSource = "ProductList"


On Error GoTo 0

End Sub


Private Sub ASales3_Change()
On Error Resume Next

Me.ASales2.RowSource = ""

On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

[Image of userform set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SavlM.jpg)

Comment: `.rowsource = "select * from ProductList where ProductID=`  something like that, not sure what unique field is coming from the combo, but say it's the ID, set a variable to it's value, then use this variable to build the criteria.  or change it to a value list, and just add the selection .AddItem, then when using tables/queries/sql switch it back

Comment: Create a String variable to store the ComboBox value before removing the RowSource, and then set the ComboBox value to this String variable at the end? But this doesn't allow people to go back, should you just "Lock" it (`.Locked = True`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by storing the selected `Value` of ASales2 in a `String` variable, see code below:

```
Private Sub ASales3_Change()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim ASales2_Selected as String

    ASales2_Selected = ASales2.Value
    ASales2.RowSource = ""

    ASales2.AddItem ASales2_Selected 'so the Item is added to the ComboBox
    ASales2.Value = ASales2_Selected 'To show the value in the ComboBox

    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: I put that in exactly as you wrote it and i caused sales2 value to disappear after entering a number into sales3.

Comment: @Seder Can you then better explain what you wish to do, as this is what I interpreted from what you posted. quote: "But I need to clear out the row source from ASales2" this is what happens, quote "but leave the selected value".

Comment: I do need to clear the row source but still show the value in ASales2, and it looks like that code should do what I want to. But when I enter a value to ASales3 the combobox for ASales2 clears completely and shows nothing.

Comment: @Seder instead of doing it at the change event from ASales3 fire above code at the exit event from ASales2